# Confused by "come" vs "go"

Tags: word-usage

> [Shall I come over to your place?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Shall+I+come+over+to+your+place%22)

Why is it "come" rather than "go" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's see if we can confuse things even more...

**Come** and **go** are deictic when they refer to travel or walking, and usually they express the point of view of the speaker.

**come {here}

go {there}**

But when you are speaking with someone, if you use the word **go**, you are referring to a place that is not where you are and also not where the person is. With **go**, you are referring to a third place where neither of you are.

Imagine a phone call:

> Hi, Jane. I am going to the library. (The speaker believes Jane is not at the library now).
>
> Hi, Jane.  I am coming to the library. (The speaker believes Jane is at the library now).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky!

The word 'come' is taken in the context of 'who is listening to you'. If that 'listener' is with you, both work -'come', and 'go'.

For instance... if Mike and Tina both are in the same room, and Mike is going somewhere. Tina can say -

> I am coming with you **OR** I am going with you.

But then, if someone is at some other place, *'come'* is more convincing.

For example, if Mike is at his place and Tina is at hers, and Tina wants to go to Mike, she'd say...

> Mike, I'm  <del>going</del> coming *(over)* to your place.

Here *'go'* won't work. However, 'go' **is** possible but then it suggests that Mike is **not** at his place.

For example Mike and Tina both are at railway station, and Mike forgot his keys at his apartment. Mike has some wound in his legs. Tina can *then* say...

> Hey, don't bother yourself. I'll *go* to your apartment to get the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the situation before using *come* or *go*.*Come* is used for movements to the place where the speaker or hearer is ( see your example) whereas *go* is used for movements to other places.

> Let's go and see Peter.

Sometimes a third person becomes the centre of our attention. We use *come* for movements to the place where he or she is (was,will be).

> He waited till two o'clock, but she didn't come.

*Come over* has one of the meanings *to visit you at your house*.

Comment: Sorry, which explanation is about which example?

Answer (score 1):

> Shall I come to your place?
>
> Shall I go to your place?

Both the sentences are correct grammatically; the use of these verbs depends on the context.

You use "come" to describe movement between the speaker and listener, and movement from another place to the place where the speaker or listener is.
Look at the following sentence.

> A to B:  Shall I come to you or to your place?

It's the place where the listener is.

> A to B: I want you to come to me or to my place.

It's the place where the speaker is.

> A to B: I am going now to the post office to send a parcel. Do you want me to come to you from there?

You usually use go to refer to movement from where the speaker or listener is to another place.

> A to B: I want you to go to Adam's house right now. I'll meet you there.

As for the sentences presented by the OP, you can use come if the listener is at their place (say their home).  However, you can use go if they aren't at their place (say they are in the market at the time of speaking to them).

Answer (score 0):

Coming results in closure of a gap between a stationary thing and the thing that moves towards it.

Going describes movement to another location.

Comment: Hi markolm. Welcome to ELL. I gather this was your first answer and I just wondered if you had noticed that that question was asked four years ago. There's nothing wrong with answering old questions of course, but the OP (original poster) is unlikely to notice your answer. Clicking on "Questions" over to the left, then "Newest" takes you to the latest posts. By the way, if you want to attract someone's attention you can begin a message with an @ sign, followed immediately by their username, as I did writing this to you. It lights up the recipient's inbox. Anyway. Welcome!

Comment: Well, I, the OP, was indeed notified of the new answer... But I agree posting answers to newer questions tend to be even more helpful

Comment: Yes, I did notice the date. This thread, nevertheless, remains a top result in Google queries relating to this particular question. So I chose to ignore it.First answer on an account does not mean first time user.